# Iterating over doctrine collections takes too much memory

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've a symfony2 command that skims over my big database and exports the data into an XML file.

This operation takes too much memory and I can see my php process when running starting to take 50 MB, then 100Mb .. and after 5 minutes it's 700MB and before it's done it takes ~800MB which is obviously huge.

How do I optimize the amount of memory used by Doctrine?

Below's how my code looks like:

```
  // Gets 4000 entities
  $entities1 = $this->doctrine->getRepository('MyBundle:Entity1')->findAll();


    foreach ($entities1 as $entity1)
    {
         // 200 entities under every entity1
         foreach ($entity1->getCollection1() as $c)
         {
               // write into an xml
         }
    }
```

Is there a way to optimize this/to do it better?

Comment: First potential problem (I can not be sure until I see code for entities): In 1st iteration you are loading from DB 4000 entities in one query. In next sub-iteration you are loading 200 entities per entity, so, you, probably, have about 4000 DB queries. And, it might be, that all of these data are in memory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest to use the doctrine "batch processing" (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html).

It allows you to handle a lot of data and to limit the php memory used. So in your case that would be something like this:

```
  $em = $this->doctrine->getManager();
  // Gets 4000 entities
  $queryEntities1 = $em->createQuery('select e from MyBundle:Entity1');
  $iterableEntities1 = $queryEntities1->iterate();

    foreach ($iterableEntities1 as $row)
    {
         $entity1 = $row[0];
         // 200 entities under every entity1
         foreach ($entity1->getCollection1() as $c)
         {
               // write into an xml
         }
         $em->detach($entity1);
    }
```

Not tested but you may need to add another query for your collection! But this way your memory will be cleaned after every entity (not sure it'll be enough in your case but you can still try to add another iterable request for the collection's foreach).

Comment: I tried this locally and the results are amazing, max used memory is 250MB :O (800MB before).

Comment: I think you can do better actually. Try to add a query in the first foreach to fetch your related entities, because when you do a `getCollection()` it'll lazy load every linked entities (which will consume a lot of memory!)